# If a complicated function $F$ satisfies $F(x,y)=R(x,y)$, where $R$ is a rational function, can we safely take limits on both sides?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, functional-equations, rational-functions

Say $F$ is a complicated real function of two variables, of which we know just a defining property, but we definitely don't have continuity, and for what it matters the defining property might even end up being contradictory - still, even if it's in order to show it's not the case, we may assume this $f$ is well defined.

If the defining property implyes that $F(x,y)=R(x,y)$ where $R$ is a rational function, is it safe to take limits on both sides, deducing information about $F$? What is the theorem that allows/forbids it?

Comment: If $F(x,y)=R(x,y)$ for all $x,y$, then $F=R$. -- If $F(x,y)=R(x,y)$ only for all $x,y$ where $F$ is defined (and this is a proper subset of where $R$ is defined), then $R$ is "only" an extension of $F$..

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh, since it's you who answered the same question as me, does that mean that the limits I take [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2836459/331175) are justified? Or have I failed  to reproduce the situation?

Comment: Your limits over there are right because the complicated $f$-expression is indeed just $\frac{x^2}{x+y}$. However, without any assumptions or deeper arguments, I do no see how $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=+\infty$ should follow - $f$ may a priori be *very* wild. In particular, $f$ is not assumed continuous - whereas at one point you write "which *would* make $1$ a discontinuity" as if that were unusual; I get the impression that you tacitly assume that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So I guess the preceding remarks about non-oscillation (oscillation meaning $\liminf_{x\to0} f(x) <+\infty$) and non-convergence are not enough? (Apart from this, I made the observation regarding $1$ only as a side note)

Comment: *I meant oscillation _implying_